# Запятушонка или тирешонка?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильны оба варианта?

> Тебе нельзя иногда покидать домишко, сына, например, когда кот в командировке.

> Тебе нельзя иногда покидать домишко, сына, — например, когда кот в командировке.

И здесь тоже оба корректны. Так?

> Ты можешь сегодня делать многое, например ты можешь пойти в Сосновку-парк.

> Ты можешь сегодня делать многое — например, ты можешь пойти в Сосновку-парк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вносим чуть-чуть изменений:

***Тебе нельзя иногда покидать домишко, сына, например когда кот в командировке*** — по [5-му пункту «Розенталя»](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137), запятая перед *когда* не ставится, т. к. здесь присоединительное значение;

***Тебе нельзя иногда покидать домишко, сына, — например, когда кот в командировке*** — нет присоединительного значения, обособление вводного слова по обычным правилам: слева тире, справа — запятая. Запятая перед тире закрывает обращение;

***Ты можешь сегодня делать многое, например ты можешь пойти в Сосновку-парк*** — *например* входит в уточняющий оборот и не отделяется от него запятой;

***Ты можешь сегодня делать многое — например, ты можешь пойти в Сосновку-парк*** — тот же современный вариант обособления вводного слова;

***Ты можешь сегодня делать многое: например, ты можешь пойти в Сосновку-парк*** — *многое* — обобщающее слово.

Comment: А сколько запятых может быть с сложном предложении? Есть какая-то норма, а то некоторые варианты прочитать и понять совершенно невозможно.  (Это чтобы было хорошо не только по Розенталю, но и для людей-читателей тоже.) И стилистика у вариантов нехороша. Это разговорная речь, а синтаксис не пойми какой,  да и лексика тоже.  Или стиль вроде как не нужно править?  Короче говоря,  есть ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ: изучаем грамматику на правильно построенных предложениях во всех отношениях. Ну и "черную графику" надо как-то корректировать. Зачем красить черным все подряд.  Заятушонки и т .д. тоже надо бы убрать.

Comment: @Sharon Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Максим, столько текста, что именно вы не поняли?  Информации в предложении немного, но форма далеко не из лучших.  Можете себе представить худ.  роман с таким предложением?

Comment: Я не понял конкретно ваших требований.

Comment: Трудно читать предложение, где много запятых. Нужно выбрать вариант с тире. Трудно читать черный шрифт.  Не обозначена тема (по тому же Розенталю).  Нет ссылок на правила.   Это к вам, а остальное к автору.  А вы тоже могли бы сделать такие замечания атору.